# Getting IndexingError while using custom function with apply in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, apply

I need to verify phone numbers as valid and invalid from my data.
I am using phonenumbers library in python

I have created a for loop which works but it is too slow so I was trying to use same for loop inside apply function but getting index error

```
    for i in range(len(df)):

        num = df.loc[i,'Primary Phone #']
        region = df.loc[i,'Override Address Country']
        try:
            output = phonenumbers.parse(num, region=region)
        except phonenumbers.NumberParseException:
            df.loc[i,'validation'] = False
        else:
            df.loc[i,'validation'] = phonenumbers.is_valid_number(output)
```

temp_data.apply(number_validation, axis = 0/1)

IndexingError: ('Too many indexers', 'occurred at index Work Order Code')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably use `apply`, like you tried, but make sure to supply the arguments:

```
def verify_number(x):
    return phonenumbers.parse(
        x['Primary Phone #'],
        region=x['Override Address Country']
    )

df.apply(verify_number, axis=1)
```

If that still is too slow, you could consider enhancing performance with `Cython`, `Numba` and `pandas.eval()`, as outlined in the [pandas user guide](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/enhancingperf.html).